# VSTS and Azure use

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy

I am trying to understand the relationship between **VSTS** and **AZURE**. 
I am planning to deploy some apps in Azure and wanted to know if there is any way within Azure that we can maintain releases and builds? or do we have to use VSTS?

**EDIT**

I currently have everything in on-premise TFS and am using on-premise MS Release Management for managing my releases (which are a bit complicated).

Now Azure does offer continuous deployment using App Service integration but I feel that might be more apt for simpler applications with relatively simple release plans (Is this assumption correct?). Exploring Azure, I also see Octopus deploy (in the compute section). Does that mean that we can manage deployment inside of Azure without using VSTS? (I currently dont care about work items, backlogs and process inside of TFS)

Comment: You can use VSTS for build and release scenario's. Though you could also use another vendo offering CI/CD tools. The advantage of using VSTS is that they are both owned by Microsoft and thus tend to stay most in sync between API versions etc.

Comment: CI/CD is not built into Azure? So for example, cant I place my source code in BitBucket and trigger a build in Azure using a webhook?

Comment: you can for webapps

Comment: @4c74356b41: that means we dont need VSTS for web apps?

Comment: that means webapps can pull code from somewhere, that doesn't mean you don't need vsts

Comment: You manage VSTS permissions using Azure Active Directory. Also you can spin test machines to run your code on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the relationship between VSTS and Azure.

1. Want to authenticate users and control access with Azure AD Team Services: [Access with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs)
2. Set up billing when you need more users, pipelines etc… [Set up billing to pay for users, pipelines, and cloud-based load testing in Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/set-up-billing-for-your-account-vs)

Regarding deploy apps to azure, there are many ways, for example:

1. [Continuous Deployment to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-continuous-deployment), the source code could be in VSTS, Git, Bitbucket etc…
2. VSTS build and release, the source code can be in VSTS, GitHub, External Git and Subversion: [Build definition repository](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/repository)
3. Some tools, for example Visual Studio: [Using Visual Studio 2015 and Deploying your first web app to your FREE Azure Subscription](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2015/07/20/using-visual-studio-2015-and-deploying-your-first-web-app-to-your-free-azure-subscription/)

Comment: I guess for deploying some applications, point 1 might not be feasible directly. I can understand that being the case for simple websites, but complicated releases would need something like Octopus deploy and/or MS Release Management. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: @Farax Yes, point 1 is used for simple deploy, otherwise other ways to deploy is better.